# Python regex works in regex tester but not in practical

Tags: python, regex

I need to match the text inside `<p>` element excluding the first `<strong>` element from the text.

When tested on an online regex tester like https://regexr.com/ it works fine, but when I run on my python script, it doesn't matches anything.

Regex:

```
<br>(.*)<\/p>$
```

Text:

```
<p><strong>Ackee and Saltfish Fritters</strong><br>\n2 cup salted Cod fish, soaked overnight<br>\n2 cloves garlic<br>\n½ medium onion<br>\n1 tsp thyme<br>\n1 tbsp cilantro<br>\n1 scallion, finely chopped<br>\n¼ scotch bonnet pepper, seeds removed<br>\n1 cup all purpose flour<br>\n1 tsp baking powder<br>\n½ cup ackee<br>\n¾ cup water<br>\nCanola oil</p>
```

Python code:

```
re.search(r"<br>(.*)<\/p>$", target_string)
```

Desired result in matches group 1:

```
\n2 cup salted Cod fish, soaked overnight<br>\n2 cloves garlic<br>\n½ medium onion<br>\n1 tsp thyme<br>\n1 tbsp cilantro<br>\n1 scallion, finely chopped<br>\n¼ scotch bonnet pepper, seeds removed<br>\n1 cup all purpose flour<br>\n1 tsp baking powder<br>\n½ cup ackee<br>\n¾ cup water<br>\nCanola oil
```

Comment: Too many problems with your regex, and besides you should be using the Beautiful Soup library here, not regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I used scrapy to get the `<p>` text, but need to extract the lines from it now without the `<strong>` element.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149556/5922398) solves the problem, I found out what was causing the regex to not work in the my script.

It was the `\n` character in the text that was causing the issue.

After removing the `\n` characters, regex worked fine. I think it's because python sees it as new line.

Posting it if anyone faces the same problem:

```
text = text.replace("\n", "")
lines = re.search("<br>(.*)<\/p>", text).groups(0)[0]
print(lines)
```

This prints:

```
2 cup salted Cod fish, soaked overnight<br>2 cloves garlic<br>½ medium onion<br>1 tsp thyme<br>1 tbsp cilantro<br>1 scallion, finely chopped<br>¼ scotch bonnet pepper, seeds removed<br>1 cup all purpose flour<br>1 tsp baking powder<br>½ cup ackee<br>¾ cup water<br>Canola oil
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already isolated the one `<p>` tag you want, you could just use `re.sub` here to string off the `<strong>` tags, e.g.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

txt = "<p><strong>Ackee and Saltfish Fritters</strong><br>\n2 cup salted Cod fish, soaked overnight<br>\n2 cloves garlic<br>\n½ medium onion<br>\n1 tsp thyme<br>\n1 tbsp cilantro<br>\n1 scallion, finely chopped<br>\n¼ scotch bonnet pepper, seeds removed<br>\n1 cup all purpose flour<br>\n1 tsp baking powder<br>\n½ cup ackee<br>\n¾ cup water<br>\nCanola oil</p>"
txt = re.sub(r'<p>(.*)</p>', '\\1', re.sub(r'<strong>.*?</strong>', '', txt), flags=re.DOTALL)
print(txt)
```

This prints:

```
<br>
2 cup salted Cod fish, soaked overnight<br>
2 cloves garlic<br>
½ medium onion<br>
1 tsp thyme<br>
1 tbsp cilantro<br>
-1 scallion, finely chopped<br>
¼ scotch bonnet pepper, seeds removed<br>
1 cup all purpose flour<br>
1 tsp baking powder<br>
½ cup ackee<br>
¾ cup water<br>
Canola oil
```